# Change app icon programmatically BUG

Tags: java, android

I'd like to change my app icon programmatically,so I search in the Internet,found that`<activity-alias>` can let it work.But there is something wrong,app icon actually changed in android launcher，but in the Recents Screen,my app icon and label name just gone,What's the reason for that?Here is my code:

```
    private void enableComponent(ComponentName componentName) {
    int state = packageManager.getComponentEnabledSetting(componentName);
    if (state == PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED) {
        return;
    }
    packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName,
            PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
            PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
}
private void disableComponent(ComponentName componentName) {
    int state = packageManager.getComponentEnabledSetting(componentName);
    if (state == PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED) {
        return;
    }
    packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName,
            PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
            PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
}
        <activity
        android:name=".activity.HelloMActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Base">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity-alias
        android:name=".triangle"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcherep"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:targetActivity=".activity.HelloMActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity-alias>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace default `<activity` to `<activity-alias` work for me